# Why does the Fourier transform map $L^2({\bf T}^n)$ "onto" $\ell^2({\bf T}^n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

A theorem regarding Fourier series in Folland's *Real Analysis* says the following:

> 8.20 **Theorem**. Let $E_k(x)=e^{2\pi ik\cdot x}$. Then $\{E_k:k\in{\bf Z}^n\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2({\bf T}^n)$.

A comment about this theorem is made in his book as follows:

> [image]

Here is my **question**:

One can certainly see that the Fourier transform is a map from $L^2({\bf T}^n)$ to $\ell^2({\bf Z}^n)$. Why can Theorem 8.20 tell that it is "onto"?

Comment: Just think about the image of the basis vectors $E_k$, and use linearity.

Comment: That the $E_k$ is an orthonormal basis really means that $$\|f\|_{L^2(\mathrm{T}^n)}^2 = \|\hat{f}\|_{l^2(\mathrm{Z}^n)}^2$$ and the operator $f \mapsto \hat{f}$ is an isomorphism of Hilbert spaces $L^2(\mathrm{T}^n) \to l^2(\mathrm{Z}^n)$

Comment: Consider taking the Fourier transform of $$\exp(2\pi i k_j x_j). $$ This is obviously in $L^2(\Bbb T^n) $ and its image under the Fourier transform is very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(a_n) \in l^2$ then defining 
$$f_n:= \sum_{j=1}^n a_j e^{2\pi i j \cdot x}$$
by orthogonality we have for all $m \leq n$
$$\| f_n -f_m\|_{2}^2 = \sum_{j=m+1}^n |a_j|^2$$

This shows that the sequence $f_n$ is Cauchy in $L^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This would give the inverse Fourier transform and thus show that it is onto. How does it relate to Theorem 8.20?

Comment: @Jack The relation $\|\sum_{j=m+1}^n a_j e^{2\pi i j \cdot x}\|_{2}^2 = \sum_{j=m+1}^n |a_j|^2$ holds for an orthonormal set, and not generally true otherwise. This is the so called Pytagora's Theorem in an inner product space.

Comment: I see. By orthonormality in Theorem 8.20, one can give the inverse Fourier transform and that's how "onto" follows from the theorem.

Comment: @Jack I might be wrong about this, but I think that you also need to use Theorem 8.20 to prove that if $f \in L^2$ then $\hat{f} \in l^2$. This is the so called Bessel inequality/Parseval identity, and it needs Orthonormality.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, the Fourier map is invertible. In more detail, if $(a_{k})$ is an $\ell^{2}$ sequence, the series
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k} a_{k} e^{2\pi ik \cdot x}$$
defines an element of $L^{2}(\mathbf{T}^{n})$ and its Fourier series is $(a_{k})$.

Comment: So, one can then use Theorem 8.20 to show that the inverse Fourier transform maps $\ell^2({\bf Z}^n)$ to $L^2({\bf T}^n)$. Thanks!